# How do I change the position of a Color Picker (JavaFX)

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I have a Color Picker but it's always located in the middle of the screen, my question is, how can I set a X and Y coordinate for the Color Picker?

I already tried `relocate` and `setlayoutX`, but that aint working either :(

```
package gui;

import display.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class JavaFXColorPicker extends Application {
private Image head;
private Image heart;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300, Color.BLACK);   
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(250,250);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();





    ColorPicker HeadColor = new ColorPicker();
    ColorPicker BodyColor = new ColorPicker();
    ColorPicker LegColor = new ColorPicker();



    HeadColor.setOnAction(new EventHandler(){

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            Color HeadPaint = HeadColor.getValue();
            Color[] HeadColorArray = new Color[]
        {
            new Color(0 , 0, 0, 1),
            HeadPaint,
            HeadPaint,
            HeadPaint,
            HeadPaint,
            new Color(1, 1, 1, 1) // de ogen
        };
            try {
                head = new display.Image(display.Parts.playerHead);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaFXColorPicker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


            head.recolour(HeadColorArray);
            Image i = head;
            gc.drawImage(i.show(), 30, 100);


        }

    });




    head = new display.Image(display.Parts.playerHead);
    Image i = head;
    gc.drawImage(i.show(), 10, 100);



    root.getChildren().add(canvas);






    root.getChildren().add(HeadColor);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Customize Character!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();




}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);


}

}
```

Comment: Try [StackPane.setAlignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html#setAlignment-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.geometry.Pos-).

Comment: Or try not using a `StackPane`, but a [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) more appropriate for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @James_D I think that this will do indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the `setlayoutX` & `setlayoutY` and worked for me.

In your case, you are using 3 Color Pickers.
Try to set the **Layout** for each one of them.

Comment: that's doctoring on symptons .. instead use a suitable layout.